# IntelliJ does not work with Java 8 after update

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So, 2 days ago everything was working perfectly. Yesterday I updated IntelliJ and now I' getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method stream() is undefined for the type List<PostVector>
Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
The method stream() is undefined for the type List<PostVector>
Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
```

`PostVector` is on of my classes.

I have everything set to Java 8 (from SDK in IntelliJ to env. variables)...

And yeah, in project in which I updated IntelliJ everything works fine, but this project in which it does not work is another project, so maybe there is a catch (but I still don't know how to fix it)

Comment: *"Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above"* Got a hint there?

Comment: Go to project settings and set source level

Comment: Source level is set to 8, project language level is also set to 8...

Comment: Maybe it's trying to keep compatible with older versions such as 1.6

Comment: That does not make any sense... As I said, in other project, everything is great and it works, but in this particular project don't... And it was working before I updated it

Comment: Do you use Maven and have there the language level under 8? Also try to invalidate caches and reimport.

Comment: Settings->Compiler->Java Compiler. Check that you have 1.8 listed there. Also, check that you have the new JDK listed in Project Structure->SDKs

Comment: So, I finnaly make it work. How? I have no freakin idea... I removed module from project and then reimported it and change directory for binary files (it was using bin directory because I started working on this project in Eclipse so I changed it to out which IntelliJ uses) and now it works.

Ty to all for ideas, but everything was set correctly

Answer (score -1):

You must wait for gwt 2.8. Lambdas are not supported before gwt 2.8 version.

You can try 2.8.0-beta1.